# Deserialize scientific notation number with RestSharp

Tags: c#, .net, deserialization, restsharp

I'm receiving from an API an object that contains the following properties

```
{
    "property": {
        "eth": 2.554e-05
    }
}
```

Now, when RestSharp deserializes my object

```
var response = await restClient.ExecuteAsync<TokenPrice>(restRequest);
```

the Eth property of my c# object will be set to 0. I tried to modify that property to a string (it will be set to null), to a decimal and to a double but I get 0 all the time.

How Could I get that number to be deserialized into my object like so

```
public class TokenPrice
{
    public decimal Eth { get; set; } -> eth = 0.00002566
}
```

? Thanks

Comment: Your C# object seems to be missing the "property" part of your JSON. You need to wrap `TokenPrice` in a class with `public TokenPrice Property {get;set;}` and then deserialize to that wrapper class.

Answer (score 3):

For request in the question you need to have types structure like below

```
public class Price
{
    public decimal eth { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public Price property { get; set; }
}
```

Then

```
var response = await restClient.ExecuteAsync<Root>(restRequest);
```